# How to check when a React Native component has finished RE-rendering?

Tags: react-native

I am currently re-rendering Child components within a Parent component based on a state change and I need to know when the child component has completely mounted and re-rendered on screen. Here's a quasi-example:

```
<Parent>
  { this.state.showChild1 ? <Child1/> : <Child2/> }
</Parent>
```

The general procedure for responding after state change would be using `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` however, this lifecycle event only fires after `state` has updated without considering the effects of what the state change would update within the `<Parent>` component.

The problem I'm encountering then is that although state has completely updated, the new Child component is not yet available because it hasn't actually finished re-rendering yet. Is there a way to check when the Child components have re-rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a callback into the component (sth like `isMounted()`) and call it in the child in the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook.

If you need this with arbitrary components you could iterate over them with `React.Children.map`([see docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map)) and add the lifecycle hooks on the fly (this is a bit error prone and you would need to have class components)

Comment: This is it! Thank you for your suggestion.